# Regex for auto-enclosing MathJax with delimiters?

Tags: php, regex, latex, pcre, mathjax

I have a problem to match math expressions and then enclose it using `\(` and `\)` delimiters.

So, given string: `If p = (\log_{a} 2) (\log_{a^{2}b} 4), then \frac{1}{p} = ....`, I'd like to match `p = (\log_{a} 2) (\log_{a^{2}b} 4)` and `\frac{1}{p}`

From string: `f'(x) = 2x + 2p, (minimum value = -p, when (x = a))`, I want to match `f'(x) = 2x + 2p` and `x = a`

This is my regex I've tried already : `[/\w|^,.\'(){}]+ *(?:[+\-*/%] *[/\w|^,.\'(){}]+ ?)* *= *[/\w|^,.\'(){}]+ *(?:[+\-*/%] *[/\w|^,.\'()]+ *)*`, it manages to match basic equation, but there's some bug such as it matches `x=a)`.   I wonder how to match parentheses (not only opening or closing).

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2147857/1339651 applies here.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger That's not what I want. Please read my question again. Please help.

Comment: Unless your content is highly structured, this won't be possible. For example, in you second example I would mark `=-p` as math. Imagine you have a variable called `a`, how would any tool know to treat this as math mode?